# Can't solve symbolic nonlinear differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

I try to solve a symbolic nonlinear differential equation, and the software keeps giving me same equation as the output!

```
DSolve[{r''[t] *r[t]^2 + G*M == 0, r[0] == R, r'[0] == vi}, r'[t], t]
```

Can you please help?

Comment: What you are encountering likely means that you are not giving the proper syntax to `DSolve`. Do GM, R, and vi have numeric values?

Comment: `DSolve[r’’[t] r[t]^2 + G == 0, r, t]` gives me an answer.  What version are you using?

Comment: `DSolve[{r''[t] r[t]^2 + G == 0, r[0] == R, r'[0] == v}, r, t]` performs "DSolve::bvimp: General solution contains implicit solutions. In the boundary value problem, these solutions will be ignored, so some of the solutions will be lost." and `{}`

Comment: Just to compare. The command of Maple `dsolve({diff(r(t), t, t)*r(t)^2 + G = 0, eval(diff(r(u), u), u = 0) = v, r(0) = R}, r(t), implicit)` performs a solution through roots of a quintic.

Comment: This is 6.188 from  a handbook of E. Kamke.

Comment: @ CA Trevillian I want them in symbolic form

Comment: Michael E2
12.1

Comment: @Bill I tied r[t], it gave me algeabric equation in r[t] to solve, but it didn't solve it

Comment: @user64494  it gave me this: Syntax::sntxf: "(" cannot be followed by "{diff(r(t),t,t)*r (t)^2+G=0,eval(diff(r(u),u),u=0)=v,r(0)=R},r(t),implicit)".

Comment: @AhmedKamalKassem: As it is written in my comment, this is a Maple command. You tried execute it in Mathematica. That is impossible.

Comment: @user64494 sorry, I misunderstood. Thanks